# Can I vectorize logical indexing to access a nested cell array?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a complex cell array with columns that hold either 1d cell arrays or 1d matrices. In each row, the dimensionality of the cell arrays is the same as the matrices, but it may vary between rows.

A toy example would look something like this

```
ex = { [1:3], {{'cat', 'dog', 'bat'}}; 
       [0:1], {{'abc', 'def'}} }
```

I also have a cell array of logical matrices that I would like to use to mask `ex`

```
mask = {[false true false];
        [true false]}
```

The desired output would be

```
after_mask = { [2], {{'dog'}}; 
               [0], {{'abc'}} }
```

### Attempts

I know that if I use a for loop, it is possible to unnest my cell array values.

```
new_col2 = cell(size(ex,1), 1);
for idx=1:size(ex,1)
    x = ex{idx, 2};
    x = [x{:}]; % Un-nest
    new_col2{idx, :} = x(mask{idx, 1});
end
```

But a for-loop seems unnecessarily messy. I'd like a vectorized solution.

**edit moved from my first self-answer**: I can also use `cellfun`. Initially, I thought this would be a vectorized solution, but after posting, Suever and rayryeng pointed out that `cellfun` is not vectorized the way `bsxfun` is.

```
function [x]=unnestAndIndex(x,y)
    x = [x{:}];
    x = x(y);
end

new_col2 = cellfun(@unnestAndIndex, ex(:,2), mask, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

It is also possible to nest `cellfun` calls instead of declaring an additional function, but again, `cellfun` is not really vectorized

```
new_col2 = cellfun(@(x, y) ...
    cellfun(@(x1) x1(y), x), ex(:,2), mask, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

**Is there a vectorized way to index my nested cell array?**

Comment: It's worth noting that `cellfun` isn't *really* vectorized, it's just a more compact representation of a for loop. Typically, it's actually going to be *slower* than the loop.

Comment: @suever that's really good to know. I was operating under the assumption that it was as efficient as bsxfun.

Comment: @Cecilia It unfortunately is not.  `cellfun` is a glorified `for` loop with extra error checking and frills.  For any processing with cells with each type being non-homogeneous, `for` loops are the best bet and you're better off writing a `for` loop as we know that the JIT will kick in eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment rayryeng says

> cellfun is a glorified for loop with extra error checking and frills.
>   For any processing with cells with each type being non-homogeneous,
>   for loops are the best bet and you're better off writing a for loop as
>   we know that the JIT will kick in eventually.

So I decided to run a benchmark on my examples from the question to test whether for loops are truly the best option.

```
ex = { [1:3], {{'cat', 'dog', 'bat'}}; ... 
       [0:1], {{'abc', 'def'}} };

mask = {[false true false]; ...
        [true false]};

display('1000 iterations with for loop');
tic;    
for it = 1:1000    
    new_col2 = cell(size(ex,1), 1);
    for idx=1:size(ex,1)
        x = ex{idx, 2};
        x = [x{:}]; % Un-nest
        new_col2{idx, :} = x(mask{idx, 1});
    end
end
toc;


display('1000 iterations with function call');
tic;
for it = 1:1000
    new_col2 = cellfun(@unnestAndIndex, ex(:,2), mask, 'UniformOutput', false);
end
toc;

display('1000 iterations with nested cellfun annonymous function');
tic;
for it = 1:1000
    new_col2 = cellfun(@(x, y) ...
        cellfun(@(x1) x1(y), x), ex(:,2), mask, 'UniformOutput', false);
end
toc;
```

The output ranks the methods from fastest to slowest as

1. For loop : 0.016249 seconds
2. `cellfun` with function call : 0.032181 seconds (2x slower than for-loop)
3. nested `cellfun` : 0.201483 seconds (10x slower than for-loop)

**For-loops win!** I am still interested in comparing to a vectorized solution, if one exists.